# Help controlling record access

Tags: role-hierarchy

I have a requirement to control record level access that I'm having trouble solving. I need to be able to share all accounts with the org(read/write) except for accounts owned by one particular user which are all on the same record type.  I also need to be able to share all opportunities with the organization that are NOT owned by this particular user.

I've made Accounts private and created a sharing rule based on record type to open up access to accounts not owned by the user and on that record type.  I'm stumbling on what to do for the opportunity sharing rules.  I want all of the opportunities in the org to be public except for those without that account owner.

What's the best approach?  Thanks in advance

Comment: I think I found a solution.  I made a custom checkbox field on the opportunity that's populated via workflow if the account owner is that user.  I then created a opportunity sharing rule that looks to this field.  It seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I think your can achieve this by make Opportunities private and then creating a criteria rule based on the owner Id of the user in question.  To set it up, follow these steps:

1. Make Opportunities private
2. Create an Opportunity sharing rule
3. Choose Rule Type of **Based on Criteria**
4. Choose **Opportunity Owner Id** with Operator **not equal to** and Value of the special user's Id.
5. Then choose to share with **All Internal Users**
6. Set Opportunity Access **Read/Write**

Now only opportunities that are NOT owned by that user will be Read/Write.

Refer to this screenshot for reference.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.   I am sorry I wasn't clear in my question above.  This particular user doesn't own any opportunities, only accounts.  Those accounts may have opportunities owned by other users.

Comment: Yep, the custom checkbox solution you defined above should work.  Nice find!